# Dealing with Follow/Followers using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

In my website I've a concept of following each other kinda twitter, I have a user connection table with the following structure,

==============================================================

**ConnectedTo | ConnectedBy | SessionID | Connect_Status | RecordDate**

==============================================================

**ConnectedTo** Holds User You Are Connecting To

**Connnected** By Holds The User Who Is Connecting

**SessionID** Again HoldsThe User Who Is Connecting

Now suppose we assume that user A Is connected to User B Table Entry will be like

===============================

**B_id | A_id | A_id | connected | date**

===============================

Now A is following B, Now Even If B Follows A Entry Will Be Like

===============================

**A_id | B_id | B_id | connected | date**

===============================

Now what I want is if both are following each Other, I've a page called network, so if am User A and I login, if I go to my network page, I should see people whom am following are following me back, but am not able to make out how should I detect that which users are following me back...It's like Google plus I gues, if you follow a user, you are following him, but if he follows you back than you are friends..so should I add 1 more field kinda say field **X** where before connecting I check if that user is following me, I should update both records as friends in field X.

And P.S I tried many things so don't ask me what I tried, I tried, and tried but still not able to makeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your user ID is `@id` and connection table name is `CONNECTION`. Then the following query will list IDs of all users who are connected back to you:

```
select 
   me2friend.ConnectedTo
from 
   CONNECTION me2friend,
   CONNECTION friend2me
where
   me2friend.ConnectedBy = @id and
   me2friend.ConnectedTo = friend2me.ConnectedBy and
   friend2me.ConnectedTo = @id
```

Comment: I am having just a single table, so what's this? 'me2friend' and 'friend2me'? there are no such fields

Comment: @V413HAV He selects the table twice, he basically does the same as Matei but with different words

Comment: @Sammaye but what should I pass in me2friend? am seriously not getting this

Comment: @V413HAV Nothing, the dual `from` he is doing selects `me2friend` as an alias of `CONNECTION` which is the table you displayed to us. So he is just aliasing your table to `me2friend` and `friend2me`. As for the SQL var `@id`, you can replace that with your PHP var as normal.

Comment: Yes, this is the idea - much better than having a separate flag to indicate that the friend relation is bidirectional. However the @ syntax is probably confusing - maybe rewrite that with a literal string, to make it easier!

Comment: If you are confused with `@` syntax, just replace `@id` to your user id PHP variable, e.g. to `$my_user_id`.

Comment: @alexkorep Done, dude, you made my day...just awesome, I need to study SQL again haha..but I still need to go through your query, you did too much in it which actually bounced over my head, a lil explanation would be helpfull

Comment: @alexkorep Is this a **SELF JOINT**?

Comment: @V413HAV Yes, I believe it's called self-join. Here is what we do in `WHERE` clause: Line 1: select my connections from table `CONNECTION` (aliased as `me2friend`). Line 2: select all connections of people belonging to my connections from table `CONNECTION` (aliased as `friend2me`). Line 3: Among them select only those connections which are connected back to me.

Comment: @alexkorep I knew it, I am bad at self joints, and thanks for the info, am finding it difficult to join this to the user info table now where I want to fetch first names last name and user status, hehe anyways thanks for explaining :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT c.ConnectedTo, cc.ConnectedBy
          FROM connections c
          LEFT JOIN connections cc ON c.ConnectedTo=cc.ConnectedBy AND cc.ConnectedTo='" . $loged['my_loged_user_id'] . "'
          WHERE c.ConnectedBy='" . $loged['my_loged_user_id'] . "'";
$sql = $mysqli->query($query);
while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
    if(isset($row['ConnectedBy'])) {
        // I'm connected with $row['ConnectedTo'] who is also following me
    } else {
       // I'm connected with $row['ConnectedTo'] but he don't follows me
    }
}
```

Comment: how can I use a left join when I've all connection in a single table?

Comment: left join should still handle it. Test it out. My suggestion is DO NOT try and add in an extra field to say they're friends, just check to see if there if they appear in B's follow list and if B appears in A's. We tried that on a site of mine... bad move.

Comment: haha I need to make a bad move too I guess, need to check in a loop always that whether the user is connected to me in return, but that's a real bad option

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a very simple problem. You simply query first to find out if the user already has a connection to see if it should be made into a mutual connection.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_connections WHERE ConnectedTo = $foreign_user_id OR connectedBy = $foreign_user_id
```

Once you have your row (or not) you judge the direction of the relation and append the user ID as needed:

```
if($result->rowCount() > 0){
    foreach($result as $row){
        if($row['ConnectedTo'] == $my_user_id) $row['ConnectedBy'] = $foreign_user_id;
        if($row['ConnectedBy'] == $my_user_id) $row['ConnectedTo'] = $foreign_user_id;
        $row['Connect_Status'] = 2; // 2 denotes that it is a mutual connection on the graph
        // Save row
        break;
    }
}else{
    // Insert new row
}
```

This is just a quick off hand answer.

It is true it is not the most elegant solution but it is one that provides more power in terms of how and when to create a mutual relationship. As you will notice a dual relationship between two people on G+ does not always mean friends. It is actually dependant upon the group you place them in as well.

### Edit

The above code will only be used when you make a new friend. When querying you can just query for all rows and then show say a label for mutual connections judged by the connect_status or you can just query for only that connect_status:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_connections WHERE Connect_status = 2
```

Will get all mutual connections.

Comment: It is easy to check when I get on his profile page, but when am in my account how can I possibly add foreign_user_id in my query? what I can only use is session id of the current user

Comment: @V413HAV How do you know who you are connecting to if you dont have the foreign user id?

Comment: see, I'll tell you, if user A is connected to B and B is connected to A, when user A visits B's profile, I check using session key of user A and get value which I pass of user b profile in the URL, but if I am in my account, and I want to see that how many users I am friends with, I don't have any foreign key, all I have is just user A user ID which I pick using in session that's it

Comment: @V413HAV Can you replace the $foreign_user_id with your own, it should work fine in that case.

Comment: Nopes I can't, than if I place all my connection in a loop I need to shoot a query always when a new user is added in my loop which is bad, I mean a user loads and he checks, ya then it may be possible

Comment: @V413HAV I am not quite getting you here, why are you putting this query in a loop? I see no reason.

Comment: wait again will go slowly ok? the table structure is same as above, now I just have user A session ID which I insert in connected by and connected to fields, so if am on other user's page, detection is easy, but if am in my account and want a list of users who i am connected with and in return they are connected to me, so basically I just have current user session ID, now currently what I do is a bad way, am looping the records to check the current user is connected with and than in a loop am using a query again to check whether that user is following me back

Comment: @V413HAV Ok yes that is bad it could shoot off `n n*2` queries for the amount of friends per page which is bad. This structure wouldn't, you would mnerely check for the Connect_Status 2 and that would be your flag to judge if this is bi-directional. So you only have one loop which is the one required by any solution which is to loop through the first query of records initially. The first loop is unavoidable, the second per friend is.

Comment: did alexkorep used a **SELF JOINT**?

Comment: @V413HAV In that particular one he used an equi-join due to the conditional used: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29